# Why error messages are not getting printed in python3.6?

Tags: python-3.x, exception, multiprocessing, try-catch

I've 11 multiprocess pool objects running simultaneously at any time, and there are like 50000 objects in total which will run, but when any of the process throws error like divisionbyzero, and terminates unexpectedly error messages are not getting printed, they only print exception message when the code is under (try : except :)block. I don't understand what is happening here, if anybody could explain me?

Answer (score 0):

This could be as a result of source code that was written before python version 3.
Print statements have been changed to a function since version 3. As a result, when you try to print an error message within an exception catch there might be a syntax error.

**Example:**

Before Version 3 Update: print "The answer is", 2*2

After: print("The answer is", 2*2)

See official documentation: 
https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html

Comment: Well I'm using python 3.6, I think its not showing error messages, because, maybe the new process is overtaking shell fast enough before i could see them.